# Problem adding developer (principal) to Device Access project

Tags: nest-device-access

I created a Device Access project in my Sandbox to test a Google Nest integration with a Home Automation provider through the SDM API. I added a developer via IAM and they have visibility to the project. In order to move it into "production," the owner of the Home Automation provider similarly created a Device Access project and applied for commercial development status which was (evidently) granted. However, the owner is unable to add additional developers to the Device Access project. He doesn't see it as a project under the Google Cloud Dashboard but sees other Google projects (not Device Access) that were created with the same Google ID. Is there something different about Device Access projects that have applied or been granted Commercial Development status that changes how additional principals are added to a project through the Google Dashboard->IAM?

Tried adding another developer by Google ID in the Google Cloud Dashboard->IAM. But the Device Access project that has applied for Commercial Development status does not show up in the Project Selection dialog in the Google Cloud Dashboard. In the case of a different Device Access project created in a Sandbox for the developer, it does show up in the Project Selection dialog and principals can be added via Google Cloud Dashboard->IAM